# Multiple ways of representing adjuncts

Tags: syntax

In previous syntax courses, I could have sworn that adjuncts were drawn as being daughter of X' and sister to X', so there are two X' levels

Eg:

[image]

In my textbook, they are represented as daughter to XP1 and sister to XP2

Eg:

[image]

Am I misreading something? Or are there multiple conventions?

Comment: Everyone has their own conventions for drawing trees! Now perhaps if they claim to follow a particular specific model then they might be consistent, but lots of models use X-bar trees.

Comment: Ah perhaps I should clarify: the second example is supposed to be using the x bar-schema as well. I understand there's a lot of variation within X-bar theory (and beyond) though.

Comment: There are multiple, recursively speciating, conventions. Every syntactician draws trees the way they want to. Trees are **not** data; they're illustrative diagrams and represent only presuppositions, and then only through their own unique conventions. Get used to it. Most of the nonterminals are irrelevant in most situations, anyway.